# Using images instead of text in menus

Tags: 7, routes, media

I have a client who wants to use images instead of text for his menu items. Is there a native way to do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: you can achieve that using CSS

Comment: I understand that, I just don't think hiding menu text with CSS is the cleanest approach, but if that is my only option, I might have to do that.

Comment: @Jane What would be _un_-clean about hiding text with CSS? Use `text-indent` with a large negative value and you have the best solution possible: looks pretty, _and_ it remains accessible for users with disabilities. Win win

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7 you can using

- [Menu Icons](https://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) module

  > This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's configuration form.
- Programmatically

  - [Allow images in menu items in Drupal 7](http://scito.ch/content/allow-images-menu-items-drupal-7) OR [Use images for menu items in Drupal](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-use-images-menu-items-drupal-simple-preprocessing-function)

Reference:

[Replacing menu items with images](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20077/replacing-menu-items-with-images#answer-20078)