# Module for floating vertical and customizable image menu

Tags: 7, routes, media

I'm looking alternative module to [ShareBar](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharebar) (but not for [social network buttons](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/54656/1908)).

The features should include:

- floating [image menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/115276/1908) items/buttons (like: [Menu Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons)) on the side linking to pre-defined paths/URLs
- ability to add new menu elements
- visible to standard user (including anonymous), not like [Quickbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickbar) which is for used for admin

Something like having [Back To Top](https://www.drupal.org/project/back_to_top) or [SnapEngage](https://www.drupal.org/project/snapengage) floating button, but with multiple menu items grouped together which are customizable.

Which modules can provide such features? Or how this can be achieved?

---

In summary, like this:

[image]

<sup>Image source: [Floating Social Share for Drupal](http://codecanyon.net/item/floating-social-share-for-drupal/9720891)</sup>

but beyond social buttons (so any button/menu item with any image/link can be added).

Comment: How about ordinary menu created with https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block with fixed position by CSS?

Comment: Could work at the end, but currently I'm investigating out-of-box solutions without front-end work involved, as it sounds like a simple functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Floating block](https://www.drupal.org/project/floating_block)** module

**Floating Block** Module page says

> The Floating block module allows you to keep html blocks, selected
>   using jquery selectors in a fixed position on the page as you scroll.
>   It works in a similar way the table header fixer in Drupal Core. This
>   means that when the user scrolls their browser selected parts of the
>   page can stay in the users view.

Comment: Then which module is good to mix to achieve menu items instead of text, is [Menu Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons) going to work with it? Or you suggest some other modules to mix with?

Comment: I have not idea with Menu Icons combination, you can try it out combining together.

Answer (score 0):

Few alternative options:

- [Menu Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons) + ([Floating Manager Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/floating_manager_menu) or CSS)
- [Taskbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/taskbar) (inspired by [AppBar](https://www.drupal.org/project/appbar)) which allows different things to be put on the bar.
- [Wunderbar!](https://www.drupal.org/project/wunderbar)
- [Floating Social Share](http://codecanyon.net/item/floating-social-share-for-drupal/9720891) module (see [live demo](http://codecanyon.net/item/floating-social-share-for-drupal/full_screen_preview/9720891)), but it require licence.

See also:

- [Adding Floating Icons with Awesome CSS3 Techniques](http://web.archive.org/web/20130811210329/http://kopepasah.com/tutorials/floating-social-icons/)